# MySQL server has gone away: Two APIs, single database, One API throws the error while other doesn't

Tags: mysql5.6

I have two flask restful API's. Both are working fine.
API1 is only for reading the database, API2 deals with update/insert. Both access the same database.

**Problem:**
API1 stops working every morning and I have to restart it everytime (once in the morning). Error is - MySQL server is gone away.
API2 always work doesn't give any error.

Earlier, I thought wait_timeout (default 8 hours) could be the reason that API1 throws that error. But, why does API2 work then?
(I use a class for database operations, and I have connect string in its init method. Also, I do not close any of the database connection. I'll very soon edit to corect it, just giving the info here to know the exact reason for that error)

Question - Why does only API1 gives that error while API2 never?

**PS** - I asked this on stackoverflow but was advised to post this here, since I never found an answer reposting here

**MySQL Config File:**

```
[mysqld]

user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
bind-address    = 127.0.0.1

key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size   = 8

myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10

query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size    = 16M
```

**Error.log**

```
2020-04-02T10:30:13.606051Z 15 [Note] Aborted connection 15 to db: 'databasename' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

The database class is like this:

```
import MySQLdb
class Db:
    parameters = ("localhost", "root", "password", "databasename")

    def __init__(self):
          conn = MySQLdb.connect(*self.parameters)
          self.cur = conn.cursor()
```

Comment: You were also told there to post the `db settings, connection parameters for both clients, and activity logs to be able to tell`. This is still true.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks for replying, Sir. I'll post them in a minute. However, I have no idea what are activity logs? Do you mean log files for each API?

Comment: Please read [ask] in the help center.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider After reading properly "How to Ask", I have finally updated the question. Please have a look whenever you are free, thanks.